# How can I access the data of users with specific UID's in Firebase Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to access the "friends"(connections) of a user in Firebase which is stored as shown in the image below:
[image]

How would I create a query to find all of the connected users that are connected to the currently logged in account and store their data so it can eventually be used in a Table View?

(if any more detail about the question is required, just ask and I can give more information on the code etc.)

Thanks.

Comment: Please remove the image an include your structure as text (Firebase Console->Export JSON). If we want to use it in an answer we have to retype it if it's an image. See [No Images](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Hi, sorry I should have taken down this question I already found the answer myself but thanks anyway.

Comment: It seems you are asking how to read all of the data in the Qbbhn.../connections node. You would not need a query for that as you can read the node directly. You would add an observer to Qbbhn/connections and iterate over the child nodes. The Firebase [Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data) coves that in the Listen For Value Events section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the answer myself. All I had to do was:

```
dataREF.REF_USERS.child(currentUserUID!).child("connections").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot.key)
})
```